# What is the difference between isomorphism and homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

I have some questions understanding isomorphism. Wikipedia said that

> isomorphism is bijective homeomorphism

I kown that $F$ is a homeomorphism if $F$ and $F^{-1}$ are continuous. So my question is: If $F$ and its inverse are continuous, can it not be bijective? Any example? I think if $F$ and its inverse are both continuous, they ought to be bijective, is that right?

Comment: You mixed up two structures: homeomorphism and homomorphism. Isomorphism is a bijective HOMOMORPHISM.

Comment: @Bartek: ***No***. For some structures, the isomorphisms are the bijective homomorphisms; but the correct definition is "homomorphism that has an inverse homomorphism".

Comment: 1. Homeomorphism is bijective in nature. 2. A map has to be bijective to have a (two-sided) inverse. 3. A one-sided inverse couple need not be bijective. It is justified by any retract of topological spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When talking about functions between sets, there is no such thing as an "inverse" in the first place if the map is not bijective. [Take a look at the relevant Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).

Moreover, when you refer to

> isomorphism is bijective homeomorphism

I think you're thinking of

> isomorphism is bijective ***homomorphism***

which, by the way, *happens* to be true in some nice cases (groups, rings, etc.), but is *absolutely not* the definition of "isomorphism" in general, and in particular, is not true for topological spaces - there are functions $f:X\to Y$ that are bijective and continuous, but are not homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphism and homeomorphism appear both in topology and abstract algebra. Here, I think you mean isomorphism and homeomorphism in topology. In one word, they are the same in topology.